# how to install custom fields if my strapi is hosted in digitalocean?

Tags: content-management-system, mern, strapi, nuxt-strapi

In the process of moving my Strapi CMS over to DigitalOcean and executing the switch from a sqlite database to PostgreSQL, I've encountered the intriguing task of integrating a custom plugin into the system. As I embark on this new installation endeavor, I'm contemplating the potential repercussions of employing the same installation approach as before. Given the substantial alterations in both the hosting environment and the database structure, I'm deliberating whether the conventional method of installation might result in unforeseen errors or compatibility issues within the revised setup. This transition has piqued my curiosity, prompting a thorough examination and consideration before implementing the plugin, ensuring the stability and functionality of the system post-installation.

In this transition phase, as I navigate the complexities of this migration and plugin installation, I'm actively seeking guidance and assistance to ensure a smooth integration. I'm open to any advice or insights that could facilitate this process.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.